# Sections do not appear in table of contents with etoc package

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, glossaries, makeindex, etoc

I use the package etoc to customize a table of contents in a Tufte-book documentclass, which contains Parts, chapters, sections, bibliography, glossary, index and "index of pieces". I use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjmulticol} 
\newlength{\rmarginW}
\setlength{\rmarginW}{\marginparwidth +\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{%    
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-\rmarginW}
        #1
\end{adjmulticols}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=piece,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Introduction}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{second section}
\chapter{second chapter}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{second section}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}

\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources bibliographiques]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title= Sources internet]
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage
\full{\printglossaries}
\clearpage
\full{\printindex}
\clearpage
\printindex[piece]
\clearpage

\newcommand*{\DotsAndPage}
{\nobreak\leaders\hbox{\bfseries\normalsize\hbox to .75ex {\hss.\hss}}%
         \hfill\nobreak
         \makebox[\rightskip][r]{\bfseries\normalsize\etocpage}\par}
     
\etocsetstyle {part}
{\parindent 0pt
\nobreak
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\centering
\etocifnumbered{Partie \etocnumber{} - }{}\etocname\par}
{}

\etocsetstyle {chapter}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
\nobreak\medskip
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
\pagebreak[1]\smallskip}
{\normalsize\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape
\etocnumber. \etocname\DotsAndPage }
{\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax }

\etocsetstyle {section}
{\leftskip1cm\rightskip .75cm \parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax
\nobreak\smallskip}
{}
{\footnotesize\sffamily\mdseries\itshape
\etocname{} (p. \etocpage). }
{\par\medskip}


\etocsettagdepth {preamble} {none}
\etocsettagdepth {linestyles} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {globalcmds} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {custom} {none}
\full{\tableofcontents}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why the sections does not appear in the table of contents, as well as the content of backmatter (bibliography, glossary and the 2 indexes.
How can these problems can be corrected?

Comment: Please supply a working example. Your code uses all kinds of commands that are incorrect, e.g. `\Part` (should be `\part`), `\full` (??), `\printbibliography` (probably needs `biblatex`.

Comment: the MWE is completed as it needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjmulticol} 
\newlength{\rmarginW}
\setlength{\rmarginW}{\marginparwidth +\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{%    
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-\rmarginW}
        #1
\end{adjmulticols}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{tocbibind}
\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2,intoc]
\makeindex[name=piece,intoc,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Introduction}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\index{Test} Test
\section{second section}
\chapter{second chapter}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{second section}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}

\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources bibliographiques]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title= Sources internet]
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage
\full{\printglossaries}
\clearpage
\full{\printindex}
\clearpage
\printindex[piece]
\clearpage

\newcommand*{\DotsAndPage}
{\nobreak\leaders\hbox{\bfseries\normalsize\hbox to .75ex {\hss.\hss}}%
         \hfill\nobreak
         \makebox[\rightskip][r]{\bfseries\normalsize\etocpage}\par}
     
\etocsetstyle {part}
{\parindent 0pt
\nobreak
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\centering
\etocifnumbered{Partie \etocnumber{} - }{}\etocname\par}
{}

\etocsetstyle {chapter}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
\nobreak\medskip
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
\pagebreak[1]\smallskip}
{\normalsize\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape
\etocnumber. \etocname\DotsAndPage }
{\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax }

\etocsetstyle {section}
{\leftskip1cm\rightskip .75cm \parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax
\nobreak\smallskip}
{}
{\footnotesize\sffamily\mdseries\itshape
\etocname{} (p. \etocpage). }
{\par\medskip}

\etocsettagdepth {preamble} {none}
\etocsettagdepth {linestyles} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {globalcmds} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {custom} {none}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\full{\tableofcontents}

\end{document}
```

**Original answer**

To get sections in the table of contents, use

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
or
\etocsettocdepth{section}
```

To get bibliography and index in the table of contents, you can use

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

Or on the `\makeindex` commands use the `intoc` option

```
\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2,intoc]
```

For the glossaries, use

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
```

And, by the way, after all your normal chapters, and before the bibliography etc. starts, use

```
\backmatter
```

I think this should cover most or all of the missing entries.

Comment: Everything works except for the bibliography where I had not put the code exactly. So I also completed this part in the MWE. In fact, with the modifications made, the 2 bibliographies are considered as sections in chapter 2 of part 2. There is no "Bibliography" chapter.

Comment: Please don't edit the code manually in your post. It doesn't work, because it is not complete. Please copy and paste a complete working example, as it is on your computer. Don't retype, because that often gives errors.

Comment: If I run your new code with the necessary corrections, I do get the Bibliography chapter.

Comment: For my part, I had to add \chapter {bibliography}  instead of \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc] to make it appears in TOC... There is probably a bug in my preamble, I'll find out where is the error in my document. Thanks!

Comment: I have added a complete working example.

Comment: I confirm that with the code as in your MWE, the chapter "bibliography" does not appear in the TOC and the two bibliographies ("sources bibliographiques" and "sources internet") appear as sections in the Fourth chapter. but if I swap the lines mentioned in my previous comment, I actually get the following error: Package hyperref warning: the anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not be the same. Added a new anchor on input line "\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources bibliographiques]".

Comment: Did you try my minimal example? Do you get the Bibliography there? Of course in this example there are no actual bibliography entries, so the sections within it are not present. May that be the difference? Or are there other differences in your actual document?